# .htaccess mod_rewrite Simplify rules: Can I simplify multiple rules to one rule?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Can I combine those two rules (with are working fine) into just one rule?

```
RewriteRule ^service/?$               service.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^service/([^/]+)/?$       service.php?id=$1 [NC]
```

Can I simplify those 4 rules into one?

```
RewriteRule ^hilfe/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$        help/help.php?content=$1_$2_$3 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^hilfe/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$                help/help.php?content=$1_$2 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^hilfe/([^/]+)/?$                        help/help.php?content=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^hilfe/?$                                help/help.php [L,NC]
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could *combine* these rules into one, although whether that is a "simplification" or not is another matter - since the single rule is more *complex*.

For example,

> ```
> RewriteRule ^service/?$               service.php [NC]
> RewriteRule ^service/([^/]+)/?$       service.php?id=$1 [NC]
> ```

Could be represented as:

```
RewriteRule ^service/?(?:([^/]+)/?)?$ service.php?id=$1 [NC]
```

You basically need to make the additional parts to the URL optional and non-capturing (ie.  `(?:<regex>)?`)

Note that the `id` parameter is always present and could therefore be empty.

> ```
> RewriteRule ^hilfe/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$        help/help.php?content=$1_$2_$3 [L,NC]
> RewriteRule ^hilfe/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$                help/help.php?content=$1_$2 [L,NC]
> RewriteRule ^hilfe/([^/]+)/?$                        help/help.php?content=$1 [L,NC]
> RewriteRule ^hilfe/?$                                help/help.php [L,NC]
> ```

Could be represented as:

```
RewriteRule ^hilfe(?:/?([^/]+)(?:/?([^/]+)(?:/?([^/]+)/?)?)?)?$ help/help.php?content=$1_$2_$3 [L,NC]
```

The *nesting* of the parenthesised subpatterns makes this harder to read (maintain, debug, etc.)

The resulting `content` URL param will always have the 3 parts (`$1`, `$2` and `$3`), except they could be empty, resulting in `content=__`, `content=foo__`, `content=foo_bar_` etc.

Comment: Thank you very much. I agree, the single rule look seems more complex. I will probably stick to the solution with multiple rules.

Comment: You're welcome. It's actually a little more complex than I first posted. since the trailing slash is optional on each of your rules (I had made it mandatory on all but the longest rule, with 3 variable parts). I've updated the "combined" rule to allow the trailing slash to be omitted on all variations. However, I too would probably stick to the solution with multiple rules.